# Can't get $.proxy to work, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use proxy inside the jQuery UI Dialog for a $.post AJAX call, but I can't seem to get it to work, it's not running the alert box, but the post is working successfully.

Here's were I'm at, this is the create button on the dialog.

```
'Create Category' : function(){
    var newCategory = $('#new-category-name').val();
    if(newCategory != ''){
    var data = {category:newCategory, ci_csrf_token: $("input[name=ci_csrf_token]").val()};
        $.post('/create/category', data, $.proxy(this.ajaxSuccess, this),'json');
    }

    ajaxSuccess = function(data)
    {
        alert ("Here");
            // Handle Data
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
},
'Cancel' : function(){
    $(this).dialog('close');
}
```

I've also tried `this.ajaxSuccess = function(data)` and `ajaxSuccess: function(data)` in the dialog initialization with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

I've also setup this fiddle if you need it: http://jsfiddle.net/CubedEye/CfmtJ/

Comment: You want to show data and close the dialog? This need to be with $.proxy?

Comment: I suppose not, just thought this was a more elegant solution. :) I've been using `$('#dialog').dialog('close');` and it works fine. I'll probably stick to that then...

Comment: Why not create a function that handles the data and close the dialog and call this inside all $.post?

Comment: Yeah, that's sound a bit nicer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the function before using it. Also, you may want to do that with the `var` keyword, so the variable is not in the global scope. See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/CfmtJ/5/.

You can also achieve this without using `$.proxy()`; you can use `$.ajax()` with the `context` option. So, the original `$.post()` would look like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            context: this,
            data: {},
            success: ajaxSuccess
        });
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/CfmtJ/6/.

Comment: Thanks so much... I knew about the ajax context thing, which is how I found out about proxy.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you could reuse your logic to handle the data and close the dialog with something like this:

```
function handleData(data, dg) {
    alert(data);
    $(dg).dialog('close');
}
//$('#add-category-dialog').ajaxSuccess(function(){
//    $(this).dialog('close');
//});
$('#add-category-dialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
     buttons: {
        'Create Category' : function(){
            $.post('/', {}, function(data){             
                handleData("test",$('#add-category-dialog'))    
            });
        },
        'Cancel': function(){
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
});
```